# Programmatically create and export WPF Viewport3D visual object in a console application on the fly

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, console-application

I am developing a wpf user control in a wpf user control library it uses Viewport3D.

I see the image in viewport on running application and I can save it to file with RenderTargetBitmap if I call it in a **WPF Application**.

But if I instantiate user control in the **console application** and try to export the empty image was saved. The code is

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(DoIt);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("press enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void DoIt()
    {
        var x = new WpfControlLibrary1.Showcase();

        x.GenerateViewPort();
        x.TakeScreenshot(300, 300);
    }
}

public partial class Showcase : UserControl
{
    private PerspectiveCamera _PerspectiveCamera = null;

    public Showcase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler((sender, e) => this.GenerateViewPort());
    }

    public void GenerateViewPort()
    {
        this._PerspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(new Point3D(0, 0, 5), new Vector3D(0, 0, -5), new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 45);

        var viewport3D = new Viewport3D() { Camera = this._PerspectiveCamera };
        viewport3D.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D() { Content = GenerateModel() });
        viewport3D.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.viewport3D_Loaded);
        this.grdAniContainer.Children.Add(viewport3D);
    }

    private static Model3DGroup GenerateModel()
    {
        ...
    }

    void viewport3D_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void TakeScreenshot(int width, int height)
    {
        takeScreenshot(this.grdAniContainer.Children[0], width, height);
    }

    private static void takeScreenshot(Visual visual, int width, int height)
    {
        var v = visual as Viewport3D;
        v.Width = width;
        v.Height = height;
        v.Measure(new Size(width, height));
        v.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));


        var vRect = new Rectangle();
        vRect.Width = width;
        vRect.Height = height;
        vRect.Fill = Brushes.White;
        vRect.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, vRect.Width, vRect.Height));

        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(vRect);
        bmp.Render(v);

        var png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

        var dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
        dlg.Filter = "PNG Images (.png)|*.png";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false == true)
        {
            string filepath = dlg.FileName;
            using (var stm = File.Create(filepath))
                png.Save(stm);
        }
    }

}
```

Load event is not fired and viewport3D_Loaded is not handle in console application, so I invoke manually.

Is there a way for loading visuals in memory and render to file programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need add this delegate after instantiate "bmp" in "takeScreenshot" method

```cs
v.Dispatcher.Invoke(((Action)(() => bmp.Render(v))), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```